# Ubuntu update error

Tags: updates

I have a Dell Inspiron mini 10 using Ubuntu which will not update - the error is

```
<:
E:/var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-2.6.24-22-lpia_2.624-22.45netbook9_lpia.deb:
files list file for package 'libxcb-shape0' is missing final newline>
```

therefore cannot use web browser - can anyone help - i am a novice i'm afraidI

Comment: Are you using bash?

Comment: I'd suggest reinstalling ASAP. While the error can be fixed, the fact that you run an unsupported release and abandoned architecture (LPIA) is not fixable. I'd recommend Xubuntu 10.04 as replacement.

Comment: Thanks. I will try. If I download 10.04 onto a usb stick, how do I load it - sorry to be a nuisance!

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try to open your terminal and follow these commands:

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get autoclean

sudo apt-get clean

sudo apt-get autoremove

sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I do not understand what I am supposed to do  - my fault, new to all this. I will try to take up mikewhatever's solution as that seems to be easier

Comment: That is not a fault. It s not easy to get used to a new OS. Termial is like cmd. Connected to ttys. It is a basic command managed gui. Apt is aplication manager ( advanced package tool) your software center. These commands will clear your package cache and help you repair broken packages (i hope)